# Execute two methods in action in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Is it possible to execute two methods in action of `<h:commandButton>`?

For example,

```
<h:commandButton action="#{bean.methodOne();bean.methodTwo();}" />
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can use [`f:actionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/actionListener.html) like this.

```
  <h:commandButton action="#{bean.methodOne()}">
    <f:actionListener binding="#{bean.methodTwo()}" />
  </h:commandButton>
```

You can add as many `f:actionListener` elements as you need.

Comment: Are those actions executed in order?

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24806943/multiple-action-listeners-with-a-single-command-component-in-jsf it says in the accepted answer "Anyway, keep in mind the listeners are always executed before the action..."

Answer (score 6):

Add a methodThree in your bean :

```
public Object methodThree() {
    methodOne();
    methodTwo();
    return someThing;
}
```

And call this method from the JSF page.

Comment: I know I can do that, but I can't call two methods in action?

Comment: From the Mojarra javadoc for the `h:commandButton` `action` attribute: _MethodExpression representing the application action to invoke when this component is activated by the user. The expression must evaluate to a public method that takes no parameters, and returns an Object (the toString() of which is called to derive the logical outcome) which is passed to the NavigationHandler for this application._

Comment: Thanks Matt. I edited my answer to reflect the fact that an object must be returned.

Comment: void is currently also allowed

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer was close to working for me but the semi-colon was throwing a parse exception. The below code worked:

```
<h:commandButton>
    <f:actionListener binding="#{bean.methodTwo()}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: You only call one method here!