# Save data of two beans with only one commandbutton in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to make a Java Project with JSF and PrimeFaces.

I have two tables. **Person** and **Address** with a relation **one to one** in database.

When I construct project with Netbeans, it created two separated **create.xthml** files. One for Address and one for Person. I'd like to **mix** them in a new single xhtml file.

My question is.. How can I **save** the data of two beans with only one commanbutton actionlistener?

I have that from two create.xhtml.

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{persona.create}" value="#{bundle.Save}" />
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{address.create}" value="#{bundle.Save}" />
```

and I need only one button.

Comment: Even if im not rly confirm about the way you do it, you can achieve this with the possible duplicate of [JSF2 execute two methods in action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912663/jsf2-execute-two-methods-in-action)

Comment: why not create just one bean for the xhtml ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this but you can try

```
<p:commandButton action="#{address.create}" actionListener="#{persona.create}" value="#{bundle.Save}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the second bean inside the first one and call create method inside.

```
public class address {
    public void create() {
        Persona persona = (Persona) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getExpressionFactory()
            .createValueExpression(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext(), "#{Persona}", Persona.class)
            .getValue(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext());
        persona.create();
}
```